# Checking out .csproj file in TFS through .NET bindings throws ItemNotFound non-fatal error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, version-control, tfs

```
/* Make some changes to .csproj file */
...
Workspace workspace    = GetWorkspace( localBranchPath, serverBranchPath );
workspace.PendEdit( csprojFilePath );
```

At this point, my non-fatal error handler for VersionControlServer catches an ItemNotFound error. However, if I run `workspace.PendEdit( csprojFilePath + ".balls" )` in the Watch window of the Visual Studio debugger, no errors occur and the file is properly checked out.

I have confirmed that the file is not marked as read-only and that the user running IIS / the app deployment and the user being impersonated both have NTFS and TFS full control permissions to the .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

TFS and its concept of 'workspaces' is likely the cause of your troubles. Weird things can happen if you have more than 1 workspace on machine. Can you log which workspace which gets acquired when you run your app in IIS ? It's likely not the same (or none at all!) as the one which Visual Studio automatically creates for you and gets/uses when you run it from VS.

**EDIT**: Just remembered something from my work when I was a 'build engineer': TFS creates workspaces *per* user and caches those for fast access in an xml files in a folder something like C:\Users[sepcific user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation ... . Check that xml file. So I'm pretty sure your user under which your IIS app pool is running under cannot see your normal user workpsace under which VS is running. Try set your own user as the IIS app pool user and see what happens. Pretty sure will work like in Visual Studio. So the mapping workspace(s) **to** *user is very concrete - you may need to create a new workspace for your IIS account & maybe download the files as well.

---

Other possibilities:
A permission issue or the IIS machine cannot see the (network ?) folder you it needs to see.

Start your Visual Studio as the user under which your application pool on IIS is running (in Windows 7 hold down `shift` & right click to see the option to run as different user) and see if you can get the same exception. If you do it's a permission issue.

If you don't get the same error go to the IIS server from the hosting location where your application is running from and try to access the path as if it would be accessed by your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've confirmed during debugging that it's the correct workspace each time (it's actually a workspace created by the code, and the only local workspace for the impersonated user). As far as network issues, it's all localhost aside from TFS, so not that. As far as permissions, I've confirmed that all relevant users have full control in both TFS and NTFS. For some more data, if I remove the .csproj from TFS during a breakpoint, PendAdd works as expected.

Comment: Can you try to run the IIS app as your user, the one you are using to login to you machine ? Just for experiment.

Comment: Thanks, and sure. I'm actually heading out now, but I can test that first thing in the morning.

Comment: Ok, can you try to change the current directory with `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` to the local folder where the crproj file is before you call GetWorkSpace method. I think this helped me resolve a similar issue once.

Comment: next step is to debug it, place `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` before the GetWorkspace and it will give you an option to debug it in Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks; I ended up taking a break from this for a while to work on some other things, but I came back to it and just got it fully working (see new answer).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were two things wrong with my code (predictably, the .csproj extension had nothing to do with it):

1. I'd been checking in a different file before the .csproj; despite my originally having recursively set non-read-only + full control, this was automatically re-setting the read-only attribute on everything, which evidently led to problems with my subsequent check-out attempts.
2. In some instances, be it because of conflicts or other reasons, I needed to do a force get latest (GetOptions.Overwrite) before modifying and checking out the .csproj file.